# Objective-C bring app to front on key press

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying trying to bring an application that is in the background to the foreground by binding to a key-press from the user even when the application does not have focus.

The affect I want is exactly like  Quicksilver / Alfred / Spotlight.

Is it possible to do this without having the user mess with any Settings inside Accessibility?

Or is this functionality prevented for security reasons? It seems some people have managed to get around this

Thanks!

PS: I am working off the example from apple with rounded window / transparency:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Registering a Global Event Listener](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:) is what you're looking for.

You can then read global key presses and call `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];` on the desired key press.

If you also want the user to be able to customise that shortcut, use [MASShortcut](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut).

Comment: Thanks, now I need to figure out how Dropbox is adding itself to the list of approved apps. For now I am just adding xcode manually but that is a temporary solution.